# Numerate certain elements uniquely in react redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a react component which will load 3rd party content and therefore needs an index. This index is based on the position prop which is an enum and will be incremented for every component with the same position.

Example:

Position a = Index a-1

Position b = Index b-1

Position a = Index a-2

I do not want to store the counter in a function or something else since the application should be stateless to avoid problems while server side rendering it. So i tried to store the counter (which needs to be reset from time to time) in redux but this caused problems since the dispatch of actions is async and i couldn't manage to increment the index for a certain position between the rendering of two components. So that i always got the index 1 for all positions even when the index in the redux state was incremented.

```
const Mycomponent = (props) => {
    // this should avoid to update the position after the initialization
    const [positionCount] = useState(props.positionCount); 

    // this should update the counter but its fired too late so that the 2. component will get the same counter as the first one
    if (positionCount === props.positionCount) {
        props.increasePositionCounter(props.position);
    }

    ...
}
```

**@Edit**
The position is given from a component above and should not be changed. But based on how many components with the same position have already been rendered, we need a different index.

The code for the increment looks like this:

```
export function exampleReducer(state, action) {
    let newState;

    switch (action.type) {
        // ...
        case actions.INCREASE_COUNTER:
            newState = {
                ...state,
                counter: {
                    ...state.counter,
                    [action.payload.position]: state.counter[action.payload.position] + 1
                }
            };
            break;
        // ...
    }

    return newState;
}
```

When i render one component with position a, it should get the index a-1. Now i render another component with the same position a and it should get the index a-2 and so on. But then i render another component with an other position, lets say b, it should get the index b-1. But i do not know where to keep track of how many components with each positions were rendered so far.
Hope that helps for a better understanding.

**@Edit2:**
I have talked to the devs of the 3rd party content and they told me about another way where i do not need the index at all. So this question is kind of solved for my case. But if anybody knows how to solve that problem, feel free to post it!

Answer (score 0):

You may simply keep track of all rendered child components with their respective positions and indexes within your state.

With that, you may easily retrieve maximum used index for elements with particular position or remove certain items:

```js
//dependencies
const { render } = ReactDOM,
      { createStore } = Redux,
      { connect, Provider } = ReactRedux
      
//store initialization
const defaultState = {
        children:[]
      },
      appReducer = (state=defaultState, action) => {
        switch(action.type){
          case 'APPEND_CHILD': {
            const {children} = state,
                  {payload:pos} = action
            if(!pos.length) return state
            const maxIndex = Math.max(0,...children
                    .filter(({position}) => position == pos)
                    .map(({index}) => index)
                   )
            return {...state, children: [...state.children,{position:pos, index:maxIndex+1}]}
          }
          default: return state
        }     
      },
      store = createStore(appReducer) 
//append child component
const AppendChildForm = ({pos,onAppendChild}) => {
  return (
    <form onSubmit={e=>(e.preventDefault(),onAppendChild(pos),e.target.reset(),pos=null)}>
      <label>Child position<input maxLength="1" onKeyUp={event => pos=event.target.value}></input></label>
      <button>Append Child</button>
    </form>
   )
}
//append child container
var mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({onAppendChild: pos =>  dispatch({type:'APPEND_CHILD',payload:pos})})
const AppendChildContainer = connect(null,mapDispatchToProps)(AppendChildForm)
//child component
const ChildComponent = ({position,index}) => <div>My position is {position} and my index is {index}</div>
//parent component
const ParentComponent = ({children}) => (
  <div>
    {children.map(({index,position},key) => <ChildComponent index={index} position={position} key={key} />)}
  </div>
)
//parent container
var mapStateToProps = ({children}) => ({children:[...children]})
const ParentContainer = connect(mapStateToProps)(ParentComponent)
//provider
render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <AppendChildContainer />
    <ParentContainer />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script><script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script><script crossorigin src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.4/redux.min.js"></script><script crossorigin src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/7.1.1/react-redux.min.js"></script><div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: That works absolutely fine in the case that you have created. But if you would execute onAppendChild automatically and multiple times at the same time, you would end up with the same problem that i have. The reducer will be called multiple times in parallel and will result in the same maxIndex before the state really updates and takes affect for the next call.

Comment: I may be missing something, but having only one action dispatched at a time is a corner stone of having your reducer pure and [predictable](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/structuring-reducers). That's why I was asking about how exactly you update your state. If you mutate your state (by different components concurrently) without invoking reducer, that's absolutely not proper thing to do and is predictably the root cause of your problem.

Comment: I always dispatch actions through the reducer and only one per component at a time.

I can try it with another example: 
Component 1 Props: index: 0; 
Component 1 calls async reducer action; 
Component 2 Props: index: 0; 
Component 2 calls async reducer action; 
Component 1 call takes affect, store index = 1; 
Component 2 call takes affect, store index = 2; 

If i render another component later on, it will work properly. But only for one component at a time.

Comment: With above approach, components will be rendered in strict accordance to the state (by the time all successfully dispatched actions have taken effect) so *asyncronousity*  may affect the order child components will get rendered in, but not break enumeration. If you may proof the opposite, I'd gladly look into live-snippet reproducing the problem you're talking about (may be, based on above demo).

Comment: Hmm, then i will try to setup a sandboxed live example and try it with some parts of your code, maybe i am wrong.